# Referenced before assignment Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, average

I have the following code:

```
#AON = Amount of Numbers to average
def general():
print "Enter how many numbers you will enter."
print "Maximum amount is 10: "
aon = raw_input()
try:
    aon = int(aon)
    if aon >= 10:
        print "I cannot average more than 10 numbers."
        general()
    else:
        start_average()
except ValueError:
    print "You entered an invalid input, try again."
    general()

def start_average():
    if aon == 1:
        print "You cannot average one number."
        general()
    elif aon == 2:
        def first_number():
            print "First number: "
            first_ni = raw_input()
            second_number()
        first_number()
        def second_number():
            print "Second number: "
            second_ni = raw_input()
            ans_two = first_ni / second_ni
        second_number()
        final_two()
    elif aon == 3:
        def third_number():
            first_number()
            second_number()
            print "Third number: "
            third_ni = raw_input()
            ans_three = ans_two / third_ni
        third_number()
        final_three()
    elif aon == 4:
        def fourth_number():
            first_number()
            second_number()
            third_number()
            print "Fourth number: "
            fourth_ni = raw_input()
            ans_four = ans_three / fourth_ni
        fourth_number()
        final_four()
    elif aon == 5:
        def fifth_number():
            first_number()
            second_number()
            third_number()
            fourth_number()
            print "Fifth number: "
            fifth_ni = raw_input()
            ans_five = ans_four / fifth_ni
        fifth_number()
        final_five


    def final_two():
        final_input = ans_two
        final_answer()
    def final_three():
        final_input = ans_three
        final_answer()
    def final_four():
        final_input = ans_four
        final_answer
    def final_five():
        final_input = ans_five
        final_answer()
    def final_six():
        final_input = ans_six
        final_answer()
    def final_seven():
        final_input = ans_seven
        final_answer()
    def final_eight():
        final_input = ans_eight
        final_answer()  
    def final_nine():
        final_input = ans_nine
        final_answer()  

    def final_answer():
        listofnumbers = [first_ni, second_ni, third_ni, fourth_ni, fifth_ni, sixth_ni, seventh_ni, eight_ni, ninth_ni]
        print "The average of your numbers:"
        print listofnumbers

        print "Is = %d." % final_input

general()
```

It's purpose is to find the average of a number, but when I run it through PowerShell, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "average.py", line 97, in <module>
general()
File "average.py", line 10, in general
general()
File "average.py", line 10, in general
general()
File "average.py", line 12, in general
start_average()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'start_average' referenced before assignment
```

I've probably done this more throughout my code, and I just made this, but I just don't know how to fix it or what is the error showing! I don't understand.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Is the call to `start_average` inside the body of the `general` function, or at the top level? Are all those other functions actually defined inside the body of `start_average`?

Comment: Meanwhile, are you intentionally going out of your way to make things complicated for yourself? Why define functions inside functions that call other functions in a chain, etc.? There are cases where such tools are useful, but learn how to ride a bicycle before trying to build and ride a monstrosity with 75 differently-sized wheels.

Comment: Also, it looks like what you're actually trying to calculate is `n1 / n2 / n3 / n4 / n5`; the mean is `(n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5) / 5`, which is very, very different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell from what you've pasted, because you've clearly broken the indentation.

But it looks like this code:

```
print "Enter how many numbers you will enter."
print "Maximum amount is 10: "
```

… is meant to be inside `general`, while this code:

```
aon = raw_input()
try:
    aon = int(aon)
    if aon >= 10:
        print "I cannot average more than 10 numbers."
        general()
    else:
        start_average()
except ValueError:
    print "You entered an invalid input, try again."
    general()
```

… is meant to be at module level.

Code is executed in the order it appears. Function definitions are just code, like anything else. So, you can't call a function before you define it, because the function doesn't exist yet.

---

You're probably about to object, with an example like this:

```
def foo():
    bar()

def bar():
    print('Hi!')

foo()
```

It looks like we're calling `bar` before it exists, and yet it works. How?

Well, the *definition* of foo is being executed before `bar` exists, but that's fine. That just defines a function that will, when run, call whatever `bar` means. As long as we've defined `bar` before we call it—and we have—everything is fine.

---

However, you have a number of similar problems in your code. For example, let's look at this part:

```
elif aon == 2:
    def first_number():
        print "First number: "
        first_ni = raw_input()
        second_number()
    first_number()
    def second_number():
        print "Second number: "
        second_ni = raw_input()
        ans_two = first_ni / second_ni
    second_number()
    final_two()
```

That `first_ni` is a local variable within the `first_number` function. Every time you call `first_number`, a new `first_ni` gets defined, but only visible within that function. You can't use it in `second_number`, because `second_number` can only see its *own* local variables, and global variables, and `first_ni` is neither.

---

The concept you need to understand is called **scope**. Python has some nice tools to help you understand scope. You can print out `locals()` and `globals()` and `dir()` at any part of your program to see what's in scope there. But you'll need to read the tutorial first.

Answer (score 1):

Indentation and a few other things are questionable. I'm not sure why you're defining all of these functions inside of other functions... I think this will do what you want. You're going to need a lot more error checking though (making sure the inputs are integers, divide by 0, etc.)

```
>>> def getMean(maxNumsToDivide):
...     listNums = []
...     for i in range(maxNumsToDivide):
...         num = raw_input("Please enter a number: ")
...         if not num:
...             break
...         listNums.append(int(num))
...     return float(sum(listNums))/len(listNums)
... 
>>> getMean(100)
Please enter a number: 2
Please enter a number: 3
Please enter a number: 4
Please enter a number: 5
Please enter a number: 3
Please enter a number: 
3.4
```

Comment: This code is by no means *good*. I didn't post it so you can use it! I posted it just to show you that a general function is usually better and requires less code. I'm sure you can write a better version.  EDIT: actually, just read abarnert's answer.